Google third app (testing) keeps dropping connection with google account
I`ve created google app (currently in testing mode, not published) to use it to connect to google calendar (my pet project, like calendly), so google keeps droping connection after a while (after week).
And when I try to use my code, I am getting this error:
"refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken"
I use Laravel 10, and google api package.
Need some explanation about this current situation, maybe google removes connection if it is in testing mode.

refresh tokens for apps in testing are only good for a week.  After a week authorization is reset and you need to authorize the app again.
just put it into production and they will stop expiring.

As I thought, thank you mate
